# Count class instances in a Python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, count, instances

I wonder what´s the best and fastest way to **count the number of occurrences of a particular object** (user-defined class instance) **in a Python list**?

For instance if we have a **class called `MyClass`**

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 42
    def foo(self):
        return “Hello world”
```

and a **list `myList`** consisting of six elements:

```
myList = [MyClass(), MyClass(), 2, 3, 'egg', MyClass()]
```

we could **count the number of occurrences of an object** which is a `MyClass` instance **by iterating `myList` and using the [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function**:

```
count = 0

for item in myList:
    if isinstance(item, MyClass):
        count += 1
```

But is there **any better** or **more pythonic** way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that kind of count using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), since `True` equals one and `False` equals zero:

```
count = sum(isinstance(x, MyClass) for x in myList)
```

Comment: or `sum(1 for x in myList if isinstance(x, MyClass))`.  As an 18 year Python user, I can't decide which is better or more 'pythonic'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Using Pythons built-in `sum()` function is a very clever idea :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for a `filter`:

```
count = len( filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, myClass), myList))
```